# Cannot set environment variables for npm-config in PowerShell

Tags: environment-variables, windows-terminal, npm-config

When I am trying to set environment variables using PowerShell in [Windows Terminal](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-terminal/9n0dx20hk701#activetab=pivot:overviewtab) with the command `set test1=value1`, I get no errors.  However, when I try to check all environment variables using the `set` command, I get the following prompt:

```
cmdlet Set-Variable at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Name[0]:
```

I read that when using PowerShell you set environment vars using this:

```
$Env:test1 = "value1";
```

I want to set the variables so that on my backend in `custom-environment-variables.json`
I can store a name by which [config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config) can extract it using config.get("test").

`custom-environment-variables.json`:

```
{
    "test": "test1",
}
```

But every time I try this, it says `Error: Configuration property "test" is not defined`.

Doing the same procedure CMD (either directly or through Windows Terminal) I get no issues whatsoever. Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  What shell are you using in Windows Terminal?  Also CMD?  PowerShell?  WSL?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I am using Windows Powershell on Windows 10. Also with cmd I meant the basic Command Prompt that windows provides.

Comment: Right - Okay, so try this.  Does it work properly when you run Windows Terminal but choose the "Command Prompt" profile?  I expect that it might.  If so, what you are really asking about is a difference between the way things operate in PowerShell vs CMD.  Windows Terminal may not factor in.  Or it might -- let me know, and add anything you find out to your question in an edit.  Thanks!

Comment: I've provided an answer that will *hopefully* help, but this is more a comment to let you know that I've also edited your question -- Please review the edit and make sure I'm still representing your question and scenario accurately.  Feel free to make additional edits, of course, if needed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the easy part:

> I get no errors but when I try to check all env. variables calling "set" I get the following prompt:

That's because the `set` command in PowerShell behaves differently.  It's an alias for the PowerShell `Set-Variable` cmdlet.  You can see this with `Get-Alias`.

Also, PowerShell variables are *not* environment variables.  As you commented, the proper way to set an environment variable in PowerShell is with:

```
$env:variablename = "value"
```

The equivalent command to `set` (to get a list of all environment variables and their values) in PowerShell is:

```
Get-ChildItem env:
# Or using the alias
dir env:
# Or using another alias
ls env:
```

This access the PowerShell "environment provider", which is essentially (my grossly oversimplified summary) a "virtual drive/filesystem" that PowerShell provides which contains the environment variables.  You can also create variables in here.

More reading:  [about_Environment_Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-7.2) from the PowerShell Doc.

---

As for the core issue with the `config` module, I haven't been able to reproduce that.  It works correctly for me in both PowerShell and CMD.  So let me run through my results in the hopes that it will help you see what might be different.  All tests were performed in Windows Terminal, although as we've determined in the comments, this is more a difference in PowerShell vs. CMD for you:

`config\default.json`:

```
{
  "test": "Original Value"
}
```

`config\custom-environment-variables.json`:

```
{
  "test": "test1"
}
```

##### CMD without `test1` variable set:

Running `node` in CMD:

```
> const config = require('config')
undefined
> config.get('test')
'Original Value'
>
```

##### CMD with `test1` variable set:

Exit Node, and back in CMD:

```
>set test1=Override
>node
```

In Node:

```
Welcome to Node.js v14.16.1.
Type ".help" for more information.
> const config = require('config')
undefined
> config.get('test')
'Override'
>
```

##### PowerShell without `test1` variable set:

```
Welcome to Node.js v14.16.1.
Type ".help" for more information.
> const config = require('config')
undefined
> config.get('test')
'Original Value'
>
```

##### PowerShell with `test1` variable set:

In PowerShell:

```
PS1> $env:test1="Override"
PS1> node
```

In Node:

```
Welcome to Node.js v14.16.1.
Type ".help" for more information.
> const config = require('config')
undefined
> config.get('test')
'Override'
>
```

---

Comment: This answers my question exactly. Not sure how I got it to work though. I tried doing exactly the same thing you did as of today and it works splendidly.

Comment: @GeorgeTrifinger Great to hear!  Don't forget to accept and upvote the answer when you get a chance - Thanks!

Comment: I really wish to upvote it but I think my reputation is too low to perform such an action. I will just accept it.